# Python Cost Function Machine Learning

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I'm doing the Boston Price Prediction Project. The problem is that when I try to calculate the `cost_function` I receive an error:

```
Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Code:

```
class Predictor():

def __init__(self):
    np.random.seed(1)
    self.w = 2 * np.random.rand(2,455) -1
    self.b = 2 * np.random.rand(1, 1) - 1

def forward_pass (self, X, w, b):
    Y_pred = np.dot(X, self.w) + self.b
    return Y_pred

def cost_function(self, Z_train, Y_train):
    **J = (1/455)*np.sum(np.square(Z_train - Y_train))**
    print(J)
    return J

def back_prop(self, X, Y, Z_train):
    dz = (2/455)*(Y - Z_train)
    dw = np.dot(dz, X.T)
    db = np.sum(dz)
    return dw, db

def gradient_descent (self, w, b, dw, db):
    self.w = self.w - 0.5*dw
    self.b = self.b - 0.5*db
    return w, b

def linear_regression_model(self, X_train, Y_train, epochs):
    w = self.w
    b = self.b
    
    costs_train = []
    
    for i in range (epochs):
        Z_train = self.forward_pass(X_train, w, b)
        cost_train = self.cost_function(Z_train, Y_train)
        print(cost_train)
        dw, db = self.back_prop(X_train, Y_train, Z_train)
        w, b = self.gradient_descent(w,b,dw,db)
        
        if i %10==0:
            costs_train.append(cost_train)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":

   predictor = Predictor()

   print ("W Aleatoria: ")
   print (predictor.w)

   print ("B Aleatoria: ")
   print (predictor.b)

   predictor.linear_regression_model(X_train, Y_train, 10000)

   print ("W Ajustada: ")
   print (predictor.w)
   print ("B Ajustada: ")
   print (predictor.b)
```

**Error**

```
ile "C:\Users\Alberto\Desktop\Oscar\UNIVERSIDAD\TFG\PROYECTOS\PRECIO CASAS BOSTON\prediction.py", line 129, in <module>
    predictor.linear_regression_model(X_train, Y_train, 10000)

  File "C:\Users\Alberto\Desktop\Oscar\UNIVERSIDAD\TFG\PROYECTOS\PRECIO CASAS BOSTON\prediction.py", line 110, in linear_regression_model
    cost_train = self.cost_function(Z_train, Y_train)

  File "C:\Users\Alberto\Desktop\Oscar\UNIVERSIDAD\TFG\PROYECTOS\PRECIO CASAS BOSTON\prediction.py", line 87, in cost_function
    J = (1/455)*np.sum(np.square(Z_train - Y_train))

  File "C:\Users\Alberto\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 635, in __array_ufunc__
    result = ops.maybe_dispatch_ufunc_to_dunder_op(

  File "pandas\_libs\ops_dispatch.pyx", line 91, in pandas._libs.ops_dispatch.maybe_dispatch_ufunc_to_dunder_op

  File "C:\Users\Alberto\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py", line 64, in new_method
    return method(self, other)

  File "C:\Users\Alberto\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 505, in wrapper
    return _construct_result(left, result, index=left.index, name=res_name)

  File "C:\Users\Alberto\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 478, in _construct_result
    out = left._constructor(result, index=index)

  File "C:\Users\Alberto\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 305, in __init__
    data = sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure=True)

  File "C:\Users\Alberto\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\construction.py", line 482, in sanitize_array
    raise Exception("Data must be 1-dimensional")

**Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional)**
```

Comment: Please format the error as code